# Android Kotlin: BuildConfig file isn't giving the correct value

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm building my project in Kotlin. In one line of my application, I am access a property in the BuildConfig file (which is a generated file, and it's being generated in Java, if that matters). BuildConfig.DEBUG is evaluating to *false* and though it's set to *true*.

Here is the line:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) // do something
```

Here is my generated BuildConfigs line:

```
public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
```

When I "go to reference" using CTRL+B or middle mouse click on BuildConfig.DEBUG, it takes me to the correct file, I *know* it's accessing the correct file.

I've stepped through the debugger already. Boolean.parseBoolean("true"); correctly returns true in the expression evaluator.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure that in your code you're importing the BuildConfig of your app and not the one of some other library? Can you change it to `com.yourapp.BuildConfig.DEBUG`?

Comment: @lelloman Both the code and the BuildConfig I'm referencing are part of a separate android module. I'm seeing elsewhere that if you're reference a BuildConfig in a android module, it's always going to be debug false. Is there anything that can be done about this?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that your module will be built with release variant by default. you can actually set the dependencies in your app explicitly, so that the debug variant of the app depends on the debug build of a module, and app release on module release.

```
dependencies {
    releaseCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: 'release')
    debugCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: 'debug')
}
```